# UnicodeEncodeError: replace or remove unicode charcter u"\u2019" from database table

Tags: python, oracle, unicode

I have a user feedback table with a column "comments".

The python code cleanses the comments column in the feedback table.
here is example of pre-processing of comments before cleansing.

```
Update Feedback set COMMENTS=Replace (COMMENTS,'%','PCT')
Update Feedback set COMMENTS=Replace (COMMENTS,'"','_')
Update Feedback set COMMENTS=Replace (COMMENTS,'','_')
```

Environment:
Oracle 11g, Python 2.7, mx_Oracle-5.1.2

python code received following error:

How can I do a Replace/remove u"\u2019" from the comments column in the Oracle database?

Appreciate any input?

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\test\Python\Cleanse_multiprocessing_1.py", line 1086, in Worker
  RemoveSpecialChar = str(RemoveSpecialChar).strip()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `str(RemoveSpecialChar)`, encode to ASCII explicitly and ignore any non-ASCII characters:

```
RemoveSpecialChar = RemoveSpecialChar.encode('ASCII', 'ignore').strip()
```

but you may want to ask yourself why you are forcing Unicode data into bytestrings in the first place.

If you wanted to replace all non-ASCII characters in the database, you could use [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) to force the data into ASCII only:

```
Update Feedback set COMMENTS=CONVERT(COMMENTS, 'US7ASCII')
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn for response. I want to remove the unicode character  \u2019 from the database table before hand. I do not want to handle this in python code.

Comment: I went further and did this, the query works in sqldeveloer but does not work from python code: Update Feedback SET COMMENTS = REGEXP_REPLACE(ASCIISTR(COMMENTS),'\\\[[:xdigit:]]{8}',''). Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @Vms: or you can do that; there is probably a better regular expression to select anything non-ASCII than using `ASCIISTR()`, but if that works for you, by all means!

Comment: @Vms: In Python the ``\\`` is interpreted as an escaped backslash. Use ``\\\\`` to produce two backslashes, or use a `r'...'` raw string.

Comment: This is what i have.             cur1.execute("Update " + TableName + " set " + f + "= REGEXP_REPLACE(ASCIISTR(" + f + "),'\\\[[:xdigit:]]{8}','')") cur1.execute("commit"). Current output: Ostrom Rd. 300\2019 N/O Rancho Rd. Expected output: Ostrom Rd. 300 N/O Rancho Rd.

Comment: @Vms: I'm not all that versed in Oracle SQL syntax and don't have an Oracle server to test on at the moment, sorry.

Comment: found a bug in the regex '\\\\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}'. Works correctly now. Thanks Again.